# Get MetaData Type from PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, metadatatype

My code below:

```
foreach (var PI in ObjType.GetProperties())
{
    var metaData = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, PI.GetType());
    string DispName = metaData.DisplayName
}
```

`ObjType` is the type of an EF6 schema first entity with `DisplayName` been added as a `Metadata` class. The error above is probably because `PI.GetType()` returns the type of the `PropertyInfo`. But I really can't figure out how to get the property itself.

I have look into various example using:

```
ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
```

However, in my case, I am not using any Lambda Expression. I just need to construct a list of the properties' `DisplayName` and pass it on.

Answer (score 0):

> But I really can't figure out how to get the property itself.

You want [PropertyInfo.PropertyType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype(v=vs.110).aspx), so change `PI.GetType()` to `PI.PropertyType`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but this is how i got the MetaDataClassType from the object it has been attached to.

Example Class with a MetadataType:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TheMetaDataYouWantTheTypeFrom))]
public class ObjectYouWantMetaDataTypeFrom
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TheMetaDataYouWantTheTypeFrom
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a username.")]
    public object Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a name.")]
    public object Name { get; set; }
}
```

The Code to get the MetadataClassType

```
Type ObjectType = ObjectYouWantMetaDataTypeFrom.GetType();
object ObjectMetaData = ObjectType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetadataTypeAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();

MetadataTypeAttribute MetaData = ObjectMetaData as MetadataTypeAttribute;
if (MetaData == null)
{ throw new NullReferenceException(); }

Type metadataClassType = MetaData.MetadataClassType;
```